# GA BigQuery Export - COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) with source/medium overcounting

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm having an issue calculating unique users in our GA BigQuery export. I've reproduced the same error using the sample data.

```
SELECT sum(users) as users, sum(sessions) as sessions FROM (
  SELECT
    h.page.pagePath as page_path,
    trafficSource.source,
    trafficSource.medium,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) AS users,
    COUNT(*) as sessions
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`, UNNEST(hits) h
  WHERE h.page.pagePath = "/home"
  GROUP BY page_path, source, medium
)
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(users) as users, sum(sessions) as sessions FROM (
  SELECT
    h.page.pagePath as page_path,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)) AS users,
    COUNT(*) as sessions
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`, UNNEST(hits) h
  WHERE h.page.pagePath = "/home"
  GROUP BY page_path
)
```

When I include the `source` and `medium` columns, the distinct `fullVisitorId` count is 10 higher than without them. How does including these columns cause an increased number of `fullVisitorId`s? This doesn't make sense to me.

What's causing this and how would I get an accurate count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does including these columns cause an increased number of fullVisitorIds? This doesn't make sense to me.

You can see why if you run your inner query like this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(fullVisitorId) AS fullVisitorId,
    h.page.pagePath as page_path,
    trafficSource.source,
    trafficSource.medium,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(TRIM(fullVisitorId))) AS users,
    COUNT(*) as sessions
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`, UNNEST(hits) h
  WHERE h.page.pagePath = "/home"
  and fullVisitorId = '9902321252073939460'
  GROUP BY page_path, source, medium
```

Which return this results:

[image]

As you can see because a user is coming from **2 different source/medium** you are counting the same user twice which cause the increase.

One option to solve this is to use aggregate function on source/medium and remove them from the `GROUP BY` like this:

```
    SELECT sum(users) as users, sum(sessions) as sessions FROM (
      SELECT
        h.page.pagePath as page_path,
        MAX(trafficSource.source) as source,
        MAX(trafficSource.medium) as medium,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(TRIM(fullVisitorId))) AS users,
        COUNT(*) as sessions
      FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`, UNNEST(hits) h
      WHERE h.page.pagePath = "/home"
      GROUP BY page_path
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sum(users) as users, sum(sessions) as sessions FROM (
      SELECT
        h.page.pagePath as page_path,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(TRIM(fullVisitorId))) AS users,
        COUNT(*) as sessions
      FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`, UNNEST(hits) h
      WHERE h.page.pagePath = "/home"
      GROUP BY page_path
    )
```

Now the number of users is the same:

[image]

Comment: @josh any feedback on this?

Comment: Figured this out in between being answered but accepted for historic purposes. Thanks for taking the time